# Help with functional subspace

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

A question on a recent exam states

*Determine whether W is a subspace of the real vector space V by either giving a proof or by providing a counterexample.*
$$V = F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$
$$W = \left \{ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f(x+1) = f(x)+1\right\}$$
for all x in R. To me this represents straight lines with gradient of 1, therefor adding two elements would lead to a straight line with gradient 2 which is not an element of W and so therefor W is not a subspace. However the answers to the exam say that W is a subspace. Are the answers possibly wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Simply $0 \notin W$, So $W$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. After all, $x,x+1\in W$ but clearly $2x+1\notin W$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f,g\in W$ then
$$(f+g)(x+1) = f(x+1)+g(x+1) = (f(x)+1) + (g(x)+1) = (f+g)(x) + 2 \neq (f+g)(x) + 1$$
so $f+g \notin W$. Thus you are right.